# Asp.Net Core - Configurable attribute route for web service

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

How do I set configurable for **api** text below. So, user can change it to any name from the appsettings.json file. Or, can I set a default text to put in the link, so any link will have this text.

[Route("**api**/[controller]")]

```
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder().SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build();

// [Route("config["ApiName"]/[controller]")]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
    // GET api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    // GET api/values/5
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public ActionResult<string> Get(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }
}
```

Comment: custom route that is configurable? I don't think that is possible. I believe parameters passed into an attribute must be constants. If youre pulling from a config this won't be the case

Comment: I also feel the same, but need a confirmation if there is a way to change it. Thanks ya.

Comment: you'd probably have better luck using the config routes section rather than attribute routing

Comment: Yup, I have done that in the config, it works. But then I'm thinking that if I got a lot of action to call from different controller, do I need to add each new route for each action to the config route?

Answer (score 1):

The ASP.NET Core [`RouteAttribute`](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/c565386a3ed135560bc2e9017aa54a950b4e35dd/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/RouteAttribute.cs) doesn't do much itself.
You can try inheriting it and reading the your configuration inside.
There's more then 1 `RouteAttribute` classes in .NET Core, so make sure you are inheriting the same one you used in your example.

It would look something like this:

```cs
public class MyDynamicRouteAttribute : RouteAttribute
{
    public MyDynamicRouteAttribute(string template) : super(FillTemplate(template)) {}

    private static string FillTemplate(string template)
    {
        var config = new ConfigurationBuilder().SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build();

        return template.Replace(<do what you need to do>);
    }
}
```

Then you would use it as you described:

```cs
[MyDynamicRoute("{ApiName}/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
    ...
}
```

**Notice that `FillTemplate()` is declared `static`. As the class hasn't been instantiated yet, you cannot call an instance method.**

I haven't tested to see how it runs, but this should get you started.

As a side note, you should probably investigate if this opens any security holes.

---

Off topic, there's probably a better way to retrieve the configuration through [Dependency Injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.2), but I've used the code you provided.